# Python Multidimension array(pointer technique: 4/5D samples build) cant save data into array

Tags: python-2.7, pointers, multidimensional-array, return-value

I have a test on building a multi-dimension array, doesn't matter it is for expert or rookie usage.

the program should run like this:

```
Main function: ask user to enter number_of_player

    read function: loop and enter name and score of each player and save them     into a dict

    assign function: check their score, assign their score to a frequency_array to determine their rank and the frequency of players of the same rank.

    search function: enable user to search and access data using name, score, location(address of player in dict), rank.

    **haven't start working**

    display function: print using the search keyword return from search function

    **haven't start working**
```

so my problem comes in, i made all the array, but data doesn't goes in to it, when i print the whole array, it appears to be blank. Please help me, I don't where i got it wrong.

```
"""
there should be 5 tier ranking syst
there should be no upper boundary for no. of player
"""
def Main():
    print "This is a eg of pointer technique(frequency dist) program \n"
    Element = 0
    score = 0
    RecordArray = {}
    scoreArray = {}
    location=0
    scoreArray[Element] = RecordArray
    totalfrequencyArray = {}
    frequencyArray1 = []
    frequencyArray2 = []
    frequencyArray3 = []
    frequencyArray4 = []
    frequencyArray5 = []
    while True:
        try:
            NElement = raw_input("number of player: ")
            NElement = int(NElement)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Integer only!"
            continue
    reply = ""
    find=""
    selection=""
    while Element != NElement:
        Element += 1
        Read(NElement, score, Element)
        Assign(NElement, Element, score, location)
        print totalfrequencyArray
    Search(find, location, selection)
    Display(selection, location, reply)


def Read(NElement, score, Element):
    Name = raw_input("\n\n\nName: ")
    while True:
        try:
            score = raw_input("Score(1-9K): ")
            score = int(score)
            if score in range(1, 9001):
                break
            else:
                print "invalid score"
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print "invalid input"
            continue
    RecordArray={}
    scoreArray={}
    RecordArray[Name] = score
    scoreArray[Element] = RecordArray
    return score
    return Element
    return NElement

"""
promblem encountered :
print function display empty array

"""
def Assign(NElement, Element, score, location):
    if score in range(1, 2000):
        location = 5
        Rank = "Tier 5"
        frequencyArray5[Element]
        frequencyArray5=frequencyArray5+[Rank]
        if Element==NElement:
            totalfrequencyArray[location]=frequencyArray5
    elif score in range(2001, 4000):
        location = 4
        Rank = "Bronze"
        frequencyArray4[Element]
        frequencyArray4=frequencyArray4+[Rank]
        if Element==NElement:
            totalfrequencyArray[location]=frequencyArray4
    elif score in range(4001, 6000):
        location = 3
        Rank = "Silver"
        frequencyArray3[Element]
        frequencyArray3=frequencyArray3+[Rank]
        if Element==NElement:
            totalfrequencyArray[location]=frequencyArray3
    elif score in range(6001, 8000):
        location = 2
        Rank = "Gold"
        frequencyArray2[Element]
        frequencyArray2=frequencyArray2+[Rank]
        if Element==NElement:
            totalfrequencyArray[location]=frequencyArray2
    elif score in range(8001, 9000):
        location = 1
        Rank = "Diamond"
        frequencyArray1[Element]
        frequencyArray1=frequencyArray1+[Rank]
        if Element==NElement:
            totalfrequencyArray[location]=frequencyArray1
    return location

def Display(selection, location, reply):
    strformat =  '{:<8}{:<20}{}'
    if selection == 0:
        print (strformat.format("", "scorelist", "ranklist"))
        for i, (Element, location) in enumerate(zip(scoreArray, totalfrequencyArray)):
            print (strformat.format(i, Element, location))

def Search(find, location, selection):
    selection=0
    return selection

Main()
```